# Returning a console.log()!

Tags: javascript, function

```js
function x() {
  return console.log("test");
}
x();
```

I understand that `x()` function should return **`undefined`** because `console.log()` function doesn't return a value.
But why does it print `"test"` in the console when I invoke the function?

Comment: Because you are calling console.log. Why should it behave different only because its result also happens to be returned?

Comment: Because console.log('test') has been invoked before returning..

Comment: what console.log returns has nothing to do with what it does when called

Comment: Thanks @Danish. It's clear now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `console.log()` is a function and is executed first before returning from the function.